# Using Summary Data as a Parameter in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to SQL and am using Access to run queries that Excel can't really handle.  Here's the basic design of the query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Description, A.Location, B.ID, B.Quantity, B.Location
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

In table B, `location` is all the same value.  I want to retain the left join above, but limit the resulting values in table A to whatever the location value is in column B.  In my mind this would be a `WHERE` clause in which `A.Location = max(B.Location)` or something like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DMax` expression to fetch the duplicated non-Null value of `B.Location`.  And that expression can be used in the `WHERE` clause to limit `A` rows to only those with matching `[Location]`:

```sql
SELECT A.ID, A.Description, A.Location, B.ID, B.Quantity, B.Location
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Location = DMax("[Location]", "B");
```

If you prefer not to use `DMax` since it is Access-specific, you can do it this way instead:

```sql
SELECT A.ID, A.Description, A.Location, B.ID, B.Quantity, B.Location
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Location = (SELECT Max([Location]) FROM B);
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks, I've never come across a DMax or DMin function.  Super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the resulting values in table A to whatever the location value is in table B, why can't you simply use the join based on `location` also?

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Description, A.Location, B.ID, B.Quantity, B.Location
FROM A LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.ID = B.ID
AND A.location = B.location
```

Comment: Because table A has all kinds of location data that I don't want.  I want to limit what is returned from table A based on whichever location is present in Table B.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry @hashbrown that was unclear.  Here's try number two: Because I want to retain rows where A.ID = B.ID but B.location is a null.  Basically, B.Location only has one value, and I want to run a WHERE clause that limits the values in A.location to be whatever that value is.